# SQL Index performance ,, which is better?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, rdbms

Is the following SQL good or bad practice from a performance perspective?

Two queries, searching by a common column:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_idx ON tbl (a, b);

SELECT id, a, b
 FROM tbl
WHERE a = @a
  AND b = @b;


SELECT id, a, b
 FROM tbl
WHERE b = @b;
```

Comment: please tag relevant RDBMS

Comment: First query better suits your index. For second query you would use single column index.

Comment: if the index is on (a,b), the query on just b will not use it.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax used

Comment: Not a pro ... but this index won't be usable to search on `b`, on `a` it will work since it is order by `a` then by `b`.

Comment: It is neither good nor bad practice, it is what it is. What's your actual question? Whether the index is useful for both queries? (It's not.) Whether you should use query 1 or query 2? (That depends on what you actually want the result to be.) Something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This index

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_idx ON tbl (a, b);
```

Will be useful for these queries

```
where a= and b =  
where a= and b>
where a like 'someval%' and b=
```

but not useful for these queries:

```
    where b=
    where a> and b=
    where a like '%someval%' and b=
    where isnull(a,'')= and b=
```

In summary, in a multicolumn index, if SQL Server was able to do a seek on first key column then the index would be useful..

Coming to your question, the first query would benefit from index you created whereas second query may tend to do a scan on this index..

There are many factors which dictate whether seek is good or bad.In some cases SQL Server may tend to not use the index available like bookmark lookup cost exceeds limit..

**References:**

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/07/seek-predicates/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/06/26/scans-vs-seeks/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-m426WYclz8

Answer (score 2):

If you reverse the index column order (b,a), then the index may be useful to both queries.  Furthermore, if `id` is the primary key implemented as a clustered index, the index will cover both queries because the clustering key is implicitly included as the row locator.  Otherwise, id could be explictly added as an included column to provide the best performance:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_idx ON tbl (a, b)
INCLUDE(id);
```